# Change Site of NAVBAR Logo Image - Overlap With Menu Items

Tags: navbar, materialize

I've followed this - [resize instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552708/is-materialize-navbar-height-adjustment-possible) - here on StackOverflow to resize the height of the MaterializeCSS navbar height. In the process, I'd like to resize the logo image. If I do so, the change from navbar to sidenav doesn't take place soon enough, and menu items overlap with the logo image. I suspect the change would have to be registered in MaterializeCSS javascript. Just wondering if anyone has already been through this and fixed the issue and can help. I can't find any reference to the problem, but perhaps I'm simply not searching the right terms.

Here is the relevant CSS I changed to change the height of the NAVBAR, and the height/position of the .logo-image.

```
.logo-image {
    height: 85px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*Change materializecss Navbar Size*/

nav {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}

nav i, nav [class^="mdi-"], nav [class*="mdi-"], nav i.material-icons {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}

nav .button-collapse i {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}

nav .brand-logo {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px){
    nav, nav .nav-wrapper i, nav a.button-collapse, nav a.button-collapse i {
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
}
```

I've played around with adding a width to the #logo-container, but that doesn't fix the problem. Again, I suspect the screen width threshold is built into javascript to allow for a certain width logo-container.

Here's an attempt at the relevant portion of html code (I think) in the form of django template code.

```
<div id="nav">
    <nav class="navigation white-text" style="background-color: #2E3192;">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container white-text" style="background-color: #2E3192;">
            <a id="logo-container" href="{{ SITE_URL }}" class="brand-logo"
               src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ SITE_SET.logo }}?v={{ REVISION }}"><img class="logo-image"
                                                                               src="
                                                                                       {{ STATIC_URL }}{{ SITE_SET.logo }}?v={{ REVISION }}"></a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
                <li><a class="dropdown-button white-text" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown4">Our Party<i
                        class="material-icons right white-text">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
                <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
                <li><a class="dropdown-button white-text" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown3">Take Action<i
                        class="material-icons right white-text">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
                <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
                <li><a class="dropdown-button white-text" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2">News & Info<i
                        class="material-icons right white-text">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
                <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
                <li><a class="dropdown-button white-text" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Accounts<i
                        class="material-icons right white-text">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav blue lighten-1">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a class="white-text" href="{{ SITE_URL }}accounts/logout/">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a class="white-text" href="{{ SITE_URL }}accounts/profile/">Profile</a></li>
                    {% if user.is_staff %}
                        <li><a class="white-text" href="{{ SITE_URL }}admin/">Admin</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <li><a class="white-text" href="{{ SITE_URL }}accounts/login/">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a class="white-text" href="{{ SITE_URL }}accounts/register/">Sign Up</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                <li><a class="white-text" href="{{ SITE_URL }}hcdp-info/">HCDP Info</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse">
                <i class="material-icons white-text">menu</i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and initialization javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    $('.parallax').parallax();
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown();
});
```

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post any code for us to look at?

Comment: I've added the css I used to change the height of the NAVBAR, and the height of the logo image.

Comment: Please provide a CodePen for it. Meanwhile, you can look at how I placed it on my website http://hbz.esy.es/

Comment: I plan to first check out your website to see if anything there will help me fix it for myself. If I can't, I will then figure out how to use CodePen... If I figure it out, I'll update here.